# How can my botched paintjob over orange peel be fixed?

Tags: painting, interior, texture, acrylic

I was repainting a small interior wall with an orange peel texture. I've repainted other walls without issue but on this cursed wall I screwed up in just about every way imaginable. Long story short, after trying to scrub and scrape off the new paint while it was still wet and only partially succeeding, there are places that look like this:

[image: Messed up paint]

There are three layers visible here. From top to bottom:

- My interior water-based acrylic eggshell paint + primer
- The previous owner's layer of water-based acrylic *exterior* eggshell paint + primer (which they inexplicably used indoors)
- Some white material which may be another layer of paint, primer, or possibly just the original wall texture.

I've been trying to read about fixing issues like this, but every article I read seems to assume a flat surface and talks about sanding the surface. However, I imagine that if I sand the wall, I'm going to flatten out and ruin the orange peel texture wherever I sand.

I can think of a few solutions here, but I'm not sure which is most appropriate or if there's another solution I can't find:

1. Completely sand all paint and texture off of the wall until it's flat, and then re-texture and repaint it (this seems like a nightmare worst-case scenario!)
2. Use paint thinner or some other solvent to remove some of the paint without removing the texture (don't know if this is even possible) and then repaint it.
3. Spray texture directly over the worst regions (if it will even stick to eggshell) and then repaint.

I'd like to be able to fix it myself, but given how badly I screwed up, if the solution isn't easy then I should probably have a professional do it. However, I'd like to have a good understanding of what's involved so I know the pro isn't either trying to rip me off or cutting corners.

Comment: I'd get some lite topping sheetrock compound, thin it even more and apply it over the cracks, then use a sponge to press it into the cracks as well as clear it out from the orange peel.  It may take a couple of coats.  Once the cracks are filled you can assess whether touch up texture is needed (readily available in spray cans), or just paint it if it's "good enough".

Comment: I agree with George the best way to hide layers is by coating with a new layer sponge finish works ok and then prime and paint.

Comment: Paint thinner for latex is water. I wouldn't use random solvents or strippers unless you want random results. I find fresh latex paint is very soft, and can be easily peeled away by keeping it wet and then  going to town with a scrub brush.  The exterior paint is not a big deal, but lack of *proper prep* is a huge deal.  You can't just slobber fresh paint on top of old, you have to clean and degrease it and scuff it up so the new paint has something to grab onto.

Comment: I would think that once prepped (as noted by [Harper](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/247014/how-can-my-botched-paintjob-over-orange-peel-be-fixed#comment486121_247014)), a new layer of primer & paint would probably blend in quite nicely here. You have a textured surface already, so some additional texture probably won't be very noticeable. Prime the wall and take a look. Add another coat if necessary (for appearance, not for "priming"), then top coat it all.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine When I had a professional painter do the bedrooms last year, he told me that with modern paint + primer, there is no need to clean or prep the wall before painting over a previous layer. I didn't believe him so we asked a sales rep at the paint supplier, and he _also_ said there was no need to clean or prep the surface. That said, we still cleaned the walls, but didn't do other prep. Lack of prep wasn't what went wrong this time, but it sounds like I should still prep before the next attempt. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks all. Last night, while staring in horror at the disaster I'd created, I wasn't thinking clearly and was stuck on the idea that I might have to sand the whole wall flat and retexture it. Now that I've slept on it, I realize that if needed I can sand and retexture part of the wall without needing to resurface the _entire_ wall.

Comment: Well, you need to knock off anything that won't stick... clean so you don't have crud in between your paint layers - and to be sure, scuff up the surface. There's no need to sand them flat, just remove the gloss. Green or burgundy Scotchbrite pads are my weapon of choice. Without that you're relying on a chemical bond (the layers infusing) and that is incompatible with being stain resistant.  Perhaps their "no need to sand" applies if you use a specific etching primer...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine Thanks! Scotchbrite pads worked great for scuffing and dulling the eggshell. We filled in cracks and gouges, and will touch up the texture in a few places next.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateUkraine We spot tested in a few small areas and found that a cotton swab dipped in rubbing alcohol can be used to dissolve the new layer of paint from the botched job without seeming to affect the layer of exterior paint underneath. If did this in a limited fashion in the worst areas, allowed it to dry for several days, and then scuffed it, do you think this would affect adhesion of the next coat?